# Restoring webview state that contains dynamically generated HTML

Tags: android, webview, state

I have a `WebView` in my application that loads dynamic content, and I want the view to persist on device rotations. So I wrote the following lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}
```

And in my onCreate():

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if(D.bug){
            Log.i(TAG, "Restoring browser state");
        }
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        if(D.bug){
            Log.i(TAG, "Not restoring browser state");
        }
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/browser_3col.html");
    }
    return mWebView;
}
```

But this effectively reloads the page. I want to pass the dynamically generated HTML.

I was thinking of dumping the entire document HTML through a `JavascriptInterface`, storing it in the outState, and then resetting it again through the `JavascriptInterface`.

Would this be a good approach? Is there no method of `WebView` that allows me to get its inner HTML?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution that would retain javascript & jvascript variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution has the following code:

in my JavaScript code:

```
window.JSInterface.dumpInnerHtml(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

in my `JavascriptInterface`:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void dumpInnerHtml(String htmlDump) {
    if (!mBrowseFragment.isDetached()) {
        mBrowseFragment.updateWebviewHtml(htmlDump);
    } 
}
```

in `onSaveInstance()`:

```
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
    outState.putString(INSTANCE_CONTAINER_HTML, mCurrentHtmlDump);
```

in `onCreate()`:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        String restoredHtml = savedInstanceState
                .getString(INSTANCE_HTML);
        if (restoredHtml != null) { 
            mWebView.loadData(restoredHtml, "text/html", "utf-8");
        }
}
```

It almost works. But I have some problems with it. It seems that loadData() does not interpret script tags. (My js functions break.), and I feel like this could be solved more elegantly.

Comment: It 2018; is saving dynamically added content in webviews still impossible? :(